# Unable to access subfolder inside iis when hosting asp.net web api application

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

I am hosting an asp.net web api application inside IIS 7. The site just works and loads the default document automatically when I navigate to `http://localhost:5555/`

But now, I need to create another folder [call it `CONTEXT`] inside the root folder and then copy all the content inside this new folder.

I ideally should be able to access the same content using `http://localhost:5555/CONTEXT`. But for some reasons, I am getting following error:

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

How can I access content under sub folder in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

First check the authentication of your website. If anonymous is enabled or the authentication you need. If you are trying to browse the folder on the browser. This needs to enable content browsing from the IIS.